# Does Stack Overflow have a policy about inbound links?

Tags: discussion, policy

Has any specific policy about acceptability of links *to* Stack Overflow *from* third parties been adopted?  How does the StackOverflow community feel about this kind of thing?

I came across this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080339/is-the-source-code-of-orbeon-forms-pe-professional-edition-available

My first thought about that product licensing question up front was: Why would someone not ask a vendor licensing question... to the vendor?

Then I found the answer: The vendor's site directs users with technical issues (that won't fit in a tweet) to post on StackOverflow: http://www.orbeon.com/community

IMO, this particular site, while not really outlining the details of what kinds of questions will be accepted on Stack Overflow, does an adequate job of instructing users on how to post (e.g. "phrase it as a question"; give a "minimal example"; "tag your question".)

Comment: As an aside, after reading the whole post attached to that that initial product licensing question, I interpret it as "Is library X version Y extensible in the same way as the vanilla library X?" which probably passes muster as a specific programming question.

Comment: The question you're discussing is a question that should be addressed to *sales* staff, not *technical staff*. It's a pre-sales question ("If I buy this, does it include this as well?"). If the sales staff isn't sure how to answer it, *they* can forward the question to their technical staff to answer.